# Slop slider at certain points

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Slider UI to go from 1 to 7. But I want the slider to stop either on one of these points, not in between. For example if I start dragging slider from "Week 1" and release it before I reach "Week 2", then the slider should snap at Week 2. How do I achieve this? For the time being I have added gameobjects on each of these week so I could use distance. But what could be the best solution?

[image: Slider]

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Slider-wholeNumbers.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay got it. It was very simple. All I had to do was change min value to 0 and max value to 6 (since I have total of 7 ranging values). Then I make sure they are all whole numbers (int).

[image: Slider]

Comment: and why not simply min to `1` and max to `7` ? ^^

Comment: @derHugo Yes that works as well. But it has been a habit of using 0 as 1 due to arrays :P